# Using Swift to reference an external C function call that uses pointers

Tags: swift, pointers

Being new to Xcode, I am trying to make use of an external C call that use pointers, and I’m having difficulty finding a way to reference them in Swift. The original call in C is defined as:

```
int32 FAR PASCAL swe_calc(double tjd, int ipl, int32 iflag, double *xx, char *serr)
```

where `xx` is a pointer to an array of 6 Doubles and `serr` is a pointer to any error message(s)

Swift sees it as:

```
int32 swe_calc(tjd: Double, ipl: Int32, iflag: int32, xx: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>, serr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>)
```

(from: https://github.com/dwlnetnl/SwissEphemeris/tree/master/SwissEphemeris)

The closest thing I’ve tried that even comes close is:

```
var serr : UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = nil; // returns any error messages from the call
var x  = [Double](count: 6, repeatedValue: 0); // array of 6 doubles returned from the call
var xx : UnsafeMutablePointer<Double> ;

xx = &x
swe_calc(2436647.0003794227, 4, 258, xx, serr)
println("xx = \(x[0]), \(x[1]), \(x[2]), \(x[3]), \(x[4]), \(x[5]), errors (if any)=\(serr)")
```

The line `xx=&x` gives the error

> Cannot assign a value of type input[(Double)] to a value of type ‘UnsafeMutablePointer’

I need a way to get/reference/use the values returned from `xx` into an array of 6 doubles, and `serr` should definitely not be an `Int8`, but a string instead. (I can get the other Java and C# versions to work, but Swift has me stumped.)

How can I make the `swe_calc` call to give it what it needs, and get out what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Both `UnsafeMutablePointer` parameters need an
array of the appropriate type passed as "inout argument" with `&`:

```
var x  = [Double](count: 6, repeatedValue: 0);
var serr = [Int8](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0)
let result = swe_calc(2436647.0003794227, 4, 258, &x, &serr)
```

Of course the arrays must be allocated large enough as expected by
the C function.

If that function puts a NUL-terminated error string into the buffer
pointed to by `serr` then you can convert it to a Swift string with:

```
let errorString = String.fromCString(&serr)
```

Comment: @nhgrif: I actually meant the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character which is abbreviated as `NUL`, and not `NULL` (as in null-pointer).

Comment: Oh, hm.  I never knew the null character was `NUL`.  Interesting.  Sorry for the edit and thanks for the education.

Comment: @nhgrif: No problem. You find that e.g. on Unix manual pages: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strlen.3.html: *"the number of characters that precede the terminating NUL character"*

Comment: FANTASTIC!!!! Worked like a charm! Thank-you. Thank-you Martin R, you're a life saver. Also, thank-you nhgrif for editing my question to make it more readable